# Regex match up to optional hash symbol?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to match **two groups**: the **first** should contain everything in front of and including the =-symbol (e.g. `spam =` ,`bar =` ). The **second group** should match everything behind =, up to, but not including the hash symbol (e.g. `True`, `42`).

```
foo = "/usr/local/bin"  # path string
eggs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1]
spam = True  # boolean
bar = 42
```

I've come up with `\(.+\s*=\s*)(.+?(?=\s*#))\`, which works great but only for lines that include the #-symbol.

Would it be possible to make the #-symbol optional?

`\(.+\s*=\s*)(.+?(?=\s*#)*)\` or `\(.+\s*=\s*)(.+?(?=\s*#*))\` don't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Like this? `(?P<var>.+? *= *)(?P<value>.+?(?= *#|$))` https://regex101.com/r/EplHkO/1

Comment: Do note that it will fail for strings like `string_hash = "this will be a big #fail"`

Comment: How to handle things like `path = "/home/tmp/valid#file#name" # comment`?

Comment: If you want to parse python source code, use the [tokenize module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html#module-tokenize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern matches characters in first group including `=` character (as you described) end the next group is matches everything after `=` excluding characters after `#`.

`(.+\s*=\s*)([^#\r\n]+)`

[Try there](https://regex101.com/r/CpD0x1/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negated character class with 2 capture groups.

```
([^=\r\n]+)=([^#\r\n]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z10SpZ/1)

If the `#` in the double quotes should be matched, you might add that to the capture group as an alternative.

```
([^=\s]+)\s*=\s*("[^"]+"|[^#]+?)\s*(?:$|#)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PJXBL7/1)

Comment: I know this is an endless rabbit hole but `test = "this will \"be a big #fail"` would fail. +1 though

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You are right of course, and we can account for that escaped double quote. Lets wait for some feedback from the OP and update it accordingly.